# Copy templated function argument in Eigen

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen, template-argument-deduction, class-template

I am writing a generic class that utilizes Eigen data types. I already have problems assigning constructor arguments to class member variables. A simplified version of my code would be:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
class A
{
public:
  Eigen::Matrix<Derived> M; // error C2976: too few template parameters

A(const Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> & V)
{
  M = V.eval(); // I would want to snapshot the value of V.
}
};
```

My question is now what data type `M` should be? I tried a variety of options, such as:

```cpp
Eigen::internal::plain_matrix_type_column_major<Derived> M;
Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> M;
```

but they just generate different errors.
Note that I use C++17 and expect the class template parameter to be inferred from the constructor.

Comment: *'too few template parameters'* – if `Eigen::Matrix` appears to be correct type for you, then stay with, but find out what the [other parameters](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) are used for and apply them appropriately (hint: you might need further template parameters for your own class, too).

Comment: How do you intend to use `A`? What types can `Derived` have? You could try [`Derived::PlainObject`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aae45af9b5aca5a9caae98fd201f47cc4), if you want to store any `Derived` type in the corresponding plain type (this automatically derives the scalar type, dimensions, etc).

Comment: I expect Derived to by a dense Matrix/Array. `V` can have fixed, dynamic, or mixed sizes.
`M` is intended to just store the values of `V`, which is the reason for the `.eval()`.
In general, `A` will compute new values based on `V` but I need to keep the input and other intermediate results for later use.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of how you intend to use `A`? I guess you essentially want to write `A a{some_expression};`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container needs the actual "plain type" as template argument:

```
template <typename PlainType>
class A
{
    PlainType M; 
public:
    template<class Derived>
    A(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & V) : M(V) {}
};
```

And you need an additional template deduction rule:

```
template<class Derived>
A(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived> & V) -> A<typename Derived::PlainObject>;
```

Usage example ([on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wugGy2)):

```
template<class X>
void bar(X&); // just to read full type of A

void foo(Eigen::Matrix2d const& M)
{
    A a = M*M;
    bar(a);  // calls bar<A<Matrix2d>>();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The declaration of the `Eigen::Matrix` variable `M` should be something like:

```
Eigen::Matrix<typename Derived::Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> M;
```

Then your code will compile. See [**Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/32sPL2).

The detailed description of each of the template parameters can be found at [this link](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html).

Comment: This is certainly possible but what would happen if the input matrix is fixed size? I assume that this information would get lost when making everything dynamic.

Comment: You can also specify integer values instead of `Eigen::Dynamic`.  See: https://godbolt.org/z/JztB4N

Comment: This would be the clearest way to do it if the Matrix size is known when the class is constructed. In my case, I intend to write a class that can take both fixed size and dynamic arguments. I cannot enforce certain matrix sizes when writing the class.

Comment: You can use `Derived::RowsAtCompileTime`, etc. But then you could also simply use `typename Derived::PlainObject` or `typename Derived::PlainMatrix`.

Answer (score 3):

A generic way of declaring your type would be to use the declaration generating it as a source, this way you don't have to look at specific ways to declare complicated template types, this is an example based on your code:

```
decltype(static_cast<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived> *>(nullptr)->eval()) M;
```

don't worry there is no nullptr dereference here because the code inside decltype is not executed.

As pointed in the comments there's a cleaner way of writing this:

```
decltype(declval<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>>().eval()) M;
```

and if you're worried that the type might be a reference and don't want that:

```
remove_reference_t<decltype(declval<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>>().eval())> M;
```

also don't forget to `#include <type_traits>` and either prefix everything with `std::` or add `using namespace std;` to your code.

To make the syntax simpler for future use add this to the beginning of your code:

```
template<typename T, typename T::f>
using member_function_return_t = remove_reference_t<decltype(declval<T>().f())>;
```

and than declare the variable as:

```
member_function_return_t<Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>, Eigen::DenseBase<Derived>::eval> M;
```

Comment: I tested this and it seems to work. I was not aware of this methodology. I was hoping that Eigen provides something more straightforward to obtain the type of a matrix or an expression.

Comment: If `Derived` is already of `Matrix` type, this will result in a const-reference to the type (which may or may not what the OP wants).

Comment: I believe `std::declval` was introduced to avoid such constructs ;)

Comment: included both your observations in the answer

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any advantage vs just writing `typename Derived::PlainObject M`.

Comment: @chtz I was just trying to offer a solution that would work in any other case with any other class without requiring knowing the internals of how something works - a generic solution to declaring variables to store data returned from a templated class member function call. The "advantage" the way I use this is that my knowledge of internals of a library I use can be minuscule, thus significantly reducing my research time into variable declarations. P.S. I never even used eigen.